# What does "crust of a rhinoceros" mean?

Tags: british-english, sentence-meaning

I've been reading *Thank You, Jeeves* by PG Wodehouse and couldn't understand what he meant by "The man must have the crust of a rhinoceros".

Comment: It probably means hide.  The hide of a rhino is thick and hard to penetrate.   If he has a think hide it means that he does not understand nuance at all (to put it mildly).  To get through to him you have to hit him over the head with a two by four (to use another idiom) even to get his attention.

Comment: 1 not enough context 2 authors often play with meanings 3 authors can use a word to be taken more than one way. impossible to say from one sentence unless someone has all of PGW memorized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Crust** in English slang means **impertinence**, according to [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crust).  You have to scroll quite far down to find this meaning.

[YourDictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/crust) gives the slang meaning as

> 5.Slang audacity; insolence; gall

In my comment, I said that crust of a rhino probably meant a thick hide that was impervious to subtlety or nuance; that one would have to hit him over the head with a two by four to even get his attention.

This is consistent with the dictionary definitions above, but with a slightly different emphasis.  Someone with the crust of a rhino has a lot of gall, and is oblivious of how offensive he is, or simply does not give a damn what other people think.